# Increase overleaf report width

Tags: margins, templates

I would like to increase the width of the overleaf report but not sure in the class I am using below which part control this. I have tried changing a few parameters but nothing seems to help. Could someone please advice? Many Thanks

```
%%%% ICLR Macros (LaTex)
%%%% Adapted by Hugo Larochelle from the NIPS stylefile Macros
%%%% Style File
%%%% Dec 12, 1990   Rev Aug 14, 1991; Sept, 1995; April, 1997; April, 1999; October 2014

% This file can be used with Latex2e whether running in main mode, or
% 2.09 compatibility mode.
%
% If using main mode, you need to include the commands
%             \documentclass{article}
%             \usepackage{iclr14submit_e,times}
%

% Change the overall width of the page.  If these parameters are
%       changed, they will require corresponding changes in the
%       maketitle section.
%
\usepackage{eso-pic} % used by \AddToShipoutPicture
%\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}

% modification to natbib citations
%\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,citesep={;},aysep={,},yysep={;}}

 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}   % let figure take up nearly whole page
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}  % let figure take up nearly whole page

% Define iclrfinal, set to true if iclrfinalcopy is defined
\newif\ificlrfinal
\iclrfinalfalse
\def\iclrfinalcopy{\iclrfinaltrue}
\font\iclrtenhv  = phvb at 8pt

% Specify the dimensions of each page

\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}


\oddsidemargin .5in    %   Note \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
\evensidemargin .5in
\marginparwidth 0.07 true in
%\marginparwidth 0.75 true in
%\topmargin 0 true pt           % Nominal distance from top of page to top of
%\topmargin 0.125in
\topmargin -0.625in
%\addtolength{\headsep}{.25in}
\addtolength{\headsep}{.05in}
\textheight 9.0 true in       % Height of text (including footnotes & figures)
\textwidth 5.5 true in        % Width of text line.
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

% \thispagestyle{empty}        \pagestyle{empty}
\flushbottom \sloppy

% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}

% Title stuff, taken from deproc.
\def\maketitle{\par
\begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}} % for perfect author
                                                        % name centering
%   The footnote-mark was overlapping the footnote-text,
%   added the following to fix this problem               (MK)
   \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
                            \hbox to1.8em{\hss $\m@th ^{\@thefnmark}$}##1}
   \@maketitle \@thanks
\endgroup
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
\gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}

% The toptitlebarf has been raised to top-justify the first page

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

% Title (includes both anonimized and non-anonimized versions)
%\def\@maketitle{\vbox{\hsize\textwidth
%\linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.1in \toptitlebar \centering
%{\LARGE\sc \@title\par}
%\bottomtitlebar % \vskip 0.1in %  minus

\ificlrfinal
    \lhead{Published as a conference paper at ICLR 2020}
    \def\And{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\@author\end{tabular}%
\else
       \lhead{Microscopy Cell Counting Using Deep Learning}
   \def\And{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil
            \begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}\ignorespaces}%
    %\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\bf\rule{\z@}{24pt}Anonymous authors\\Paper under double-blind review\end{tabular}%
\fi
%\vskip 0.3in minus 0.1in}}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{\vskip.075in\centerline{\large\sc
Abstract}\vspace{0.5ex}\begin{quote}}{\par\end{quote}\vskip 1ex}

% sections with less space
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.3ex
minus0.2ex}{\Large\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}}

\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-1.8ex plus
-0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.8ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-1.5ex
plus      -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.5ex plus
.2ex}{\normalsize\sc\raggedright}}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{1.5ex plus
0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{1.5ex plus
  0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\sc}}
\def\subsubsubsection{\vskip
5pt{\noindent\normalsize\rm\raggedright}}


% Footnotes
\footnotesep 6.65pt %
\skip\footins 9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3pt \hrule width 12pc \kern 2.6pt }
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

% Lists and paragraphs
\parindent 0pt
\topsep 4pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
\partopsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parskip .5pc


%\leftmargin2em
\leftmargin3pc
\leftmargini\leftmargin \leftmarginii 2em
\leftmarginiii 1.5em \leftmarginiv 1.0em \leftmarginv .5em

%\labelsep \labelsep 5pt

\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
   \labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
   \topsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
   \parsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
   \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
    \labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
    \topsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
    \parsep \z@ \partopsep 0.5pt plus 0pt minus 0.5pt
    \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginiv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
     \labelwidth\leftmarginvi\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\abovedisplayskip 7pt plus2pt minus5pt%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip  0pt plus3pt%
\belowdisplayshortskip  4pt plus3pt minus3pt%

% Less leading in most fonts (due to the narrow columns)
% The choices were between 1-pt and 1.5-pt leading
%\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{11pt}\xpt\@xpt} % got rid of @ (MK)
\def\normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{16pt}\xpt\@xpt}
\def\small{\@setsize\small{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\footnotesize{\@setsize\footnotesize{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\scriptsize{\@setsize\scriptsize{8pt}\viipt\@viipt}
\def\tiny{\@setsize\tiny{7pt}\vipt\@vipt}
\def\large{\@setsize\large{14pt}\xiipt\@xiipt}
\def\Large{\@setsize\Large{16pt}\xivpt\@xivpt}
\def\LARGE{\@setsize\LARGE{20pt}\xviipt\@xviipt}
\def\huge{\@setsize\huge{23pt}\xxpt\@xxpt}
\def\Huge{\@setsize\Huge{28pt}\xxvpt\@xxvpt}

\def\toptitlebar{\hrule height4pt\vskip .25in\vskip-\parskip}

\def\bottomtitlebar{\vskip .29in\vskip-\parskip\hrule height1pt\vskip
.09in} %
%Reduced second vskip to compensate for adding the strut in \@author


%% % Vertical Ruler
%% % This code is, largely, from the CVPR 2010 conference style file
%% % ----- define vruler
%% \makeatletter
%% \newbox\iclrrulerbox
%% \newcount\iclrrulercount
%% \newdimen\iclrruleroffset
%% \newdimen\cv@lineheight
%% \newdimen\cv@boxheight
%% \newbox\cv@tmpbox
%% \newcount\cv@refno
%% \newcount\cv@tot
%% % NUMBER with left flushed zeros  \fillzeros[<WIDTH>]<NUMBER>
%% \newcount\cv@tmpc@ \newcount\cv@tmpc
%% \def\fillzeros[#1]#2{\cv@tmpc@=#2\relax\ifnum\cv@tmpc@<0\cv@tmpc@=-\cv@tmpc@\fi
%% \cv@tmpc=1 %
%% \loop\ifnum\cv@tmpc@<10 \else \divide\cv@tmpc@ by 10 \advance\cv@tmpc by 1 \fi
%%    \ifnum\cv@tmpc@=10\relax\cv@tmpc@=11\relax\fi \ifnum\cv@tmpc@>10 \repeat
%% \ifnum#2<0\advance\cv@tmpc1\relax-\fi
%% \loop\ifnum\cv@tmpc<#1\relax0\advance\cv@tmpc1\relax\fi \ifnum\cv@tmpc<#1 \repeat
%% \cv@tmpc@=#2\relax\ifnum\cv@tmpc@<0\cv@tmpc@=-\cv@tmpc@\fi \relax\the\cv@tmpc@}%
%% % \makevruler[<SCALE>][<INITIAL_COUNT>][<STEP>][<DIGITS>][<HEIGHT>]
%% \def\makevruler[#1][#2][#3][#4][#5]{\begingroup\offinterlineskip
%% \textheight=#5\vbadness=10000\vfuzz=120ex\overfullrule=0pt%
%% \global\setbox\iclrrulerbox=\vbox to \textheight{%
%% {\parskip=0pt\hfuzz=150em\cv@boxheight=\textheight
%% \cv@lineheight=#1\global\iclrrulercount=#2%
%% \cv@tot\cv@boxheight\divide\cv@tot\cv@lineheight\advance\cv@tot2%
%% \cv@refno1\vskip-\cv@lineheight\vskip1ex%
%% \loop\setbox\cv@tmpbox=\hbox to0cm{{\iclrtenhv\hfil\fillzeros[#4]\iclrrulercount}}%
%% \ht\cv@tmpbox\cv@lineheight\dp\cv@tmpbox0pt\box\cv@tmpbox\break
%% \advance\cv@refno1\global\advance\iclrrulercount#3\relax
%% \ifnum\cv@refno<\cv@tot\repeat}}\endgroup}%
%% \makeatother
%% % ----- end of vruler

%% % \makevruler[<SCALE>][<INITIAL_COUNT>][<STEP>][<DIGITS>][<HEIGHT>]
%% \def\iclrruler#1{\makevruler[12pt][#1][1][3][0.993\textheight]\usebox{\iclrrulerbox}}
%% \AddToShipoutPicture{%
%% \ificlrfinal\else
%% \iclrruleroffset=\textheight
%% \advance\iclrruleroffset by -3.7pt
%%   \color[rgb]{.7,.7,.7}
%%   \AtTextUpperLeft{%
%%     \put(\LenToUnit{-35pt},\LenToUnit{-\iclrruleroffset}){%left ruler
%%       \iclrruler{\iclrrulercount}}
%%   }
%% \fi
%% }
%%% To add a vertical bar on the side
%\AddToShipoutPicture{
%\AtTextLowerLeft{
%\hspace*{-1.8cm}
%\colorbox[rgb]{0.7,0.7,0.7}{\small \parbox[b][\textheight]{0.1cm}{}}}
%}
```

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to set the margins like that (the lines from `\oddsidemargin` to `\textheight` as these are not particularly intuitive (especially since a reference point sits at (1in,1in) or something like that. Better to use the `geometry` package. It has a `key=value` based interface and is much more intuitive to use

Comment: Do I need to use this in the style file? or can i use it in the main tex file? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use it in the main document.